# Exception caused by one-to-many bidirectional relationship

Tags: java, jpa

I have a two entities relationship, I believe that I did all fine, but when I try to run my application, Payara is launching this error:

> Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-7154] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.4.payara-p2): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
> Exception Description: The attribute [retenciones] in entity class [class komp.model.ChequePropio] has a mappedBy value of [chequepropio] which does not exist in its owning entity class [class komp.model.RetencionChp]. If the owning entity class is a @MappedSuperclass, this is invalid, and your attribute should reference the correct subclass.

Here one of entities causing the problem:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "chequepropio", uniqueConstraints = {
@UniqueConstraint(name = "ukchequepropio", columnNames = {"idbanco", "idempresa",   "idtipo", "numero"})})
public class ChequePropio implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy = "chequepropio")
    private List<RetencionChp> retenciones;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

The other entities:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "retencionchp")
public class RetencionChp implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "idcheque", insertable = true, updatable = true)
    private ChequePropio chequePropio;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public ChequePropio getChequePropio() {
        return chequePropio;
    }

    public void setChequePropio(ChequePropio chequePropio) {
        this.chequePropio = chequePropio;
    }
}
```

I can't see any error in the relationship, somebody could say me what is wrong?
Thanks in advance!
Fernando

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is self-explanatory:

> The attribute [retenciones] in entity class [class
> komp.model.ChequePropio] has a mappedBy value of [chequepropio] which
> does not exist in its owning entity class

Mind the keyword `chequepropio`. You don't have a `chequepropio` property in `RetencionChp`. You have a `chequePropio` instead. Mind the uppercase `P`. The following should solve it (`mappedBy = "chequePropio")`).

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "chequepropio", uniqueConstraints = {
@UniqueConstraint(name = "ukchequepropio", columnNames = {"idbanco", "idempresa",   "idtipo", "numero"})})
public class ChequePropio implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy = "chequePropio")
    private List<RetencionChp> retenciones;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```